# iPhone games development basics

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I want to develop games for iPhone and I am using Cocos 2D, I have some experience on developing iPhone apps, but quite new to games. So what i want to ask is that what is the best tutorial to learn game development for iPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are great tutorials about Cocos2d (but not only) on the [Ray Wenderlich's blog](http://www.raywenderlich.com/). Ray Wenderlich is the co-author of the [Learning Cocos2D book](http://cocos2dbook.com/).

Answer (score 5):

Though it doesn't utilize Cocos2D, [71Squared.com](http://www.71squared.com) has some fantastic tutorials on beginning iPhone game development.

Answer (score 4):

There is a good book for cocos2d called "Learning Cocos2D". It is the one that I used to start game development.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a book recomeneded by Cocos2D website - [Cocos2d Book](http://cocos2dbook.com/).